# How do you use regex on a word that cannot contain a number in java?

Tags: regex, string, matching

Basically, I want to use regular expressions to return false if the string contains "word" AND is followed by a number, i.e. returning false if "theword1", "theword2", "theword5" etc.

However, I still want it to return true if it is just "theword" without a number or a completely different string like "apple5" - the word and number have to be together to return false. I know it can be done but I really am stuck.

Here is what I've tried so far (doesn't work):

```
str.matches(".*([word][^1-9])*.*")
```

My logic was 0 or more characters `(.*)` word NOT next to a number occurring 0 or more times `(([word][^1-9])*)` and then 0 or more characters afterwards.

Comment: Must the “word” be literally a word? ie not part of a larger word? So should  “theWordFoo" match? Or "hello worldtheWord foo"?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `[word][^1-9]` that you tried consists of 2 character classes. It will first match a single character, one of `w` `o` `r` `d` followed by a single character other than a digit 1-9

You can exclude the match by asserting not word followed by a digit in the string.

```
^(?!.*word\d).+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pY56GA/1)

Answer (score 0):

Match on “word” when not followed by a digit implement as a negative look ahead:

```
boolean hasUnnumberedWord(String str, String word) {
    return str.matches(".*" + word + "(?!\\d).*");
}
```

If “word” could contain characters that had special meaning in regex, use `Pattern.quote(word)` instead or `word`.